# Continuity of partial derivatives of $f(x,y)^t:= \frac{x^2y}{x^6+2y^2} $ when $(x,y)^t\neq (0,0)^t $ and $0$ otherwise

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x,y)^t:= \begin{cases} \frac{x^2y}{x^6+2y^2} &, (x,y)^t\neq (0,0)^t \\
                       0 &, (x,y)^t=(0,0)^t
                     \end{cases}$

($(.)^t$ means transponed)

I need to determine the partial derivatives of $f$ and decide where the derivatives are continuous.

So for $(x,y)^t \neq (0,0)^t$:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{-4x^7y+4xy^3}{(x^6+2y^2)^2}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{x^8-2x^2y^2}{(x^6+2y^2)^2}$

And for $(x,y)^t = (0,0)^t$:

$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{s}(f(s,0)^t-f(0,0)^t)=0=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{s}(f(0,s)^t-f(0,0)^t)$.

Now let $(x_n,y_n)^t \in \mathbb{R}^2 \neq (0,0)^t$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(x_n,y_n)^t=(0,0)^t$.
I need to check if $\frac{-4x^7y+4xy^3}{(x^6+2y^2)^2}$ with $x:=x_n, y:=y_n$ converges to $0$ and the same for $\frac{x^8-2x^2y^2}{(x^6+2y^2)^2}$ which they don't according to maple.

But how do I prove this?

I thought about defining $x_n,x'_n$ and $y_n,y'_n$ which all converge to zero but $\frac{-4x_n^7y_n+4x_ny_n^3}{(x_n^6+2y_n^2)^2} \neq$ the same with ${x'}_n$ instead of $x_n$

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel the need to transpose all of your inputs.  Elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are typically represented as tuples $(x,y)$ (not column vectors).  The only reason that you would bother writing the transpose is if you were trying to view elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as vectors, but $f$ isn't a linear map, and you don't seem to be using the vector space structure of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so why bother?

Comment: Is f(x,y) continuous at (0,0)?  Consider $\lim_\limits{x\to 0} f(x,x^3).$  If $f$ is discontinuous at (0,0) is it possible for $f_x,$ or $f_y$ to be continuous?

Comment: lih, not sure whether you have had Lagrange multipliers yet. The comment of @DougM  can be reconstructed, without much difficulty, by  looking for the maximum of $x^2 y$ under the constraint $x^6 + 2 y^2$ constant. In this case we have a certain nonzero constant $C$ and extrema at $y = \pm C x^3.$ The main points are that (A) the method is fairly easy for this type of problem and (B) it shows that $f(x,y)$ is not even bounded near the origin. In sum, I suggest you check for continuity first.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily show with the definition that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$

Now we need to check if $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{-4x^7y+4xy^3}{(x^6+2y^2)^2} \neq 0$$

By taking polar coordinates: $$x=r \cos{t}$$ $$y=r\sin{t}$$ we have that:

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{4r^8 \cos^7{t}\sin{t}+4r^4 \cos{t} \sin^3{t}}{(r^6\cos^6{t}+2r^2\sin^2{t})^2}=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{4r^4 \cos^7{t}\sin{t}+4 \cos{t} \sin^3{t}}{(r^4\cos^6{t}+2\sin^2{t})^2}$$

You can see that  for this last limitwe gain different values for different values of $t$ (for example $t=0,\frac{\pi}{4}$)thus the limit does not exist.

So the first partial derivative of $f$ is not continuous at the origin.

Apply the same method for the other partial derivative to check its continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Because of $f(x,0)=f(0,y)=0$ the partial derivatives (of any order) in $(0,0)$ exist, and are zero.

But $f$ is not continuous in $0$, since $(\frac 1n,\frac 1n)$ is mapped via $f$ into an unbounded sequence.